# Unable to hide categories within the archive loop

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using the events calendar plugin from Modern Tribe. I am attempting to hide a specific event category from the archive views. I have added the following code to functions.php but it give me some weird results. On the initial page load, the events with the specified category to exclude are indeed not visible, but if you paginate forward and then back again, the events appear with the category I am trying to exclude.

I have written to the plugins support team who are also baffled as to why this code will not work. I am hoping someone here might shed some light.

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'exclude_events_category' );

function exclude_events_category( $query ) {
if(is_post_type_archive( $post_types = 'tribe_events' )) {
    $query->set( 'tax_query', array(

        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'tribe_events_cat',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => 'online',
            'operator' => 'NOT IN'
        )
        )
    );
}
return $query;
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to contact the author of the plugin? You would probably get a more precise and detailed response.

Comment: Hi Jeff, I did that and they were as baffled as me. I think I mentioned that in my question, sorry if it wasn't clear.

Comment: Can you try disabling other plugins, perhaps one of them is overriding what you're attempting to do.

Comment: Hi Tony, yes I had already tried that and stripping all other code from function.php (except enqueue)

Answer (score 0):

On the line 3, remove `$post_types` and just have `is_post_type_archive('tribe_events')`

Comment: Hi, thanks but I got the same result. As soon as you paginate away and then back, the events I need to exclude come back.